# How can I automate a verification and execution macro on several tables, each of which is processed with a specific SAS code?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

"I've created some SAS code to check whether the SAS info-center tables are up to date for the program run. First, I check if we're in the execution range. Then, for each table, I check the table properties to see if it has been updated today. I also check whether the code on this table was executed yesterday or not, based on the 'Evaluation_Maj' column ('update OK' or 'Update KO'). Finally, I insert it in the Controle_MajTableSAS table so that I can check it the following day.
You can examine the code I've applied to just two tables. I currently have 13 different tables. I'd like to automate this check for all the tables and optimize my code (it contains a lot of repetition), but I don't know how to do it?

```
%macro Execution;
    %let current_date = %sysfunc(today());

    /*output table update date*/
    proc sql;
        select (datepart(modate))
        into :modified_CONTRAT
        from dictionary.tables
        where libname IN('LS') and memname in('CONTRAT')
        ;
    quit;
    proc sql;
        select (datepart(modate))
        into :modified_TCHOBQ
        from dictionary.tables
        where libname IN('LST') and memname in('TCHOBQ')
        ;
    quit;

    /* Execution days are the first 3 days of the month except Sunday*/

%if ( (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=2 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=1) OR
      (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=2 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=2) OR
      (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=2 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=3) OR
      (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=3 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=1) OR
      (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=3 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=2) OR
      (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=3 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=3) OR
      (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=4 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=1) OR
      (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=4 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=2) OR
      (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=4 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=3) OR
      (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=5 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=1) OR
      (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=5 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=2) OR
      (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=5 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=3) OR
      (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=6 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=1) OR
      (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=6 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=2) OR
      (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=6 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=3) OR
      (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=7 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=1) OR
      (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=7 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=2) OR
      (%sysfunc(weekday(&current_date.))=7 and %sysfunc(day(&current_date.))=3) )

     
%then %do;
    %put "The program is running";


%macro CONT;

/*checking if the table has been updated yesterday, 
if yes then no execution otherwise  execution*/
proc sql;
 select Evaluation_Maj into :Evaluation_CONTRAT from ASG.Controle_MajTableSAS
        where Nom_Table='CONTRAT' and Annee_Execution=year(today()) and 
        Mois_Execution=month(today()) and Jour_Execution=day(today())-1 ;
        quit;

%if ( %sysfunc(year(&modified_CONTRAT.))=%sysfunc(year(&current_date.)) and 
 %sysfunc(month(&modified_CONTRAT.))=%sysfunc(month(&current_date.)) and
 %sysfunc(day(&modified_CONTRAT.))=%sysfunc(day(&current_date.)) and 
  "&Evaluation_CONTRAT" ="update KO                                         " )

 %then %do;
data CONT;
set LSCONTRA.CONTRAT;
run;
/*following code........*/
%end;
%else %do;
%put 'table was already imported yesterday' ;
%end;
%mend CONT;
%CONT;

%macro TCHOBQ;
proc sql;
 select Evaluation_Maj into :Evaluation_TCHOBQ from ASG.Controle_MajTableSAS
        where Nom_Table='TCHOBQ' and Annee_Execution=year(today()) and 
        Mois_Execution=month(today()) and Jour_Execution=day(today())-1 ;
        quit;

%if ( %sysfunc(year(&modified_TCHOBQ.))=%sysfunc(year(&current_date.)) and 
 %sysfunc(month(&modified_TCHOBQ.))=%sysfunc(month(&current_date.)) and
 %sysfunc(day(&modified_TCHOBQ.))=%sysfunc(day(&current_date.)) and 
  "&modified_TCHOBQ" ="update KO                                         " )
 %then %do;
 proc sql;
insert into ASG.SI 
select *,Date() as DateImport from LST.TCHOBQ;
;
quit;
/*following code.........*/
%end;
%else %do;
%put 'table was already imported yesterday' ;
%end;
%mend TCHOBQ;
%TCHOBQ;

/*store the update to follow processing next day*/
proc sql;
INSERT into ASG.Controle_MajTableSAS 
    select memname as Nom_Table , 
    year(today()) as Annee_Execution,
    month(today()) as Mois_Execution,
    day(today()) as Jour_Execution,
    cat(year(datepart(modate)),'/',month(datepart(modate)),'/',day(datepart(modate))) as Date_MAJ_TableSAS,
    case when  
     memname='TCHOBQ' and year(&modified_TCHOBQ.)=year(&current_date.) and 
     month(&modified_TCHOBQ.)=month(&current_date.) and 
     day(&modified_TCHOBQ.)=day(&current_date.) then 'update OK' 
    when 
    memname='CONTRAT' and year(&modified_CONTRAT.)=year(&current_date.) and 
    month(&modified_CONTRAT.)=month(&current_date.) and 
    day(&modified_CONTRAT.)=day(&current_date.) then 'update OK'  
    else 'update KO' end as Evaluation_Maj
from dictionary.tables
where libname IN('LS', 'LST') and memname in('CONTRAT','TCHOBQ')
;
 quit;


%end;
    %else %do ;
     %put " No execution necessary.";
     %end;
  %mend Execution ; 
  %Execution ;
```